# How to Switch User programatically using C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I have windows 2003 server and want to switch users programatically using c#. I have list of all active user so how can I switch the user ?

I need to capture the screen of all users which are logon currently.

Thanks
Laxmilal

Comment: Do you need to switch users or list all logged on users? Which one? Logged on where?

Comment: I am able to list all users using 'cassia" library. Now need to capture the screen to jpg file to track what are they doing ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear what you want to achieve.

There are several ways to have a program run as a different user than the logged in one (or have the program execute another process with different credentials):

- Use `runas`, supplying the credentials for the other user
- In C#, use `Process.Start` with `ProcessStartInfo`. This lets you provide the credentials under which the process should run
- Windows services require an account to run - this can be a different user than the logged in one (and will run whether someone is logged on or not)

You can't change the credentials of an *already* running process.

Can you explain *exactly* what you are trying to achieve? Perhaps there are other ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: I need to capture the screen of all users which are logon currently.

Comment: @user219909 - That's not what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute actions with impersonations(with a specific username and password) in ASP .Net.

If it's a windows application you just start a process with different username described in here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed04yy3t.aspx

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

You mean like if you lock the screen and log on with someone else? That is totally impossible. You know the login screen says you need to press ctrl-alt-del, it is designed so that noone can mess with that. You can impersonate users however, like with the runas command, but you need to know their passwords for that.

Comment: I don't think so, probably a service can do that, cause it is alive when the user logged out.

Comment: a service impersonates an account. This is not the same as messing with the active user session.

Comment: AFAIK not only services can impersonate.