# Windows OS User switching during black box testing

Tags: c#, windows

I have a test that is as follows:

```
As a user, when I run the application
and I do X
Then I switch users
and I run the application
then Y
```

Assertions X and Y I can test easily enough, but how do I automate the switching of Users on the host OS? Also, this test needs to be ran from an automated build server.

Comment: Looking at other solutions to this question here, it looks like it isn't really possible to physically log out after doing X and back in as another user for Y. Instead, the `runas` command seems to be the way to go. Assuming I understood the question. [See the post here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537535/how-to-switch-user-programatically-using-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't want to log out. I want both applications running under different user profiles. Does that change your answer?

Comment: So why would `runas` not suit your needs? It doesn't log anyone out.